# ImportError: cannot import name sandbox

Tags: google-app-engine-python

Over the past couple days, this has started cropping up whenever I run `dev_appserver.py`:

```
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox
ImportError: cannot import name sandbox
```

Since I was primarily coming across this in the setup of a new environment, I figured it must be a mistake of mine during setup. After enough head-scratching over the past 3 hours, I figured it couldn't be in the new setup, so I loaded up `dev_appserver.py` in a known-to-be-working environment.

Yet again:

```
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox
ImportError: cannot import name sandbox
```

None of my app code had been changed, so it *had* to be something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It turned out the SDK had changed.**

I had a file named `appengine_config.py` that (specifically for the development server) whitelisted a couple of C modules.

```
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python import sandbox
sandbox._WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES += ['_ssl', '_socket']
```

When I disabled these lines, this issue was replaced with another (the one that was the reason those lines were there to mitigate):

```
File "[...]/devappserver2/python/runtime/sandbox.py", line 1091, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named _socket
```

Notice the `runtime` piece in the filepath? Apparently the location of the sandbox module had changed. So I added `.runtime` to the import path:

```
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.python.runtime import sandbox
```

Then, after re-enabling those lines, everything was working again! ✅ Mission accomplished.